# How to display logo in center inline with menu?

Tags: html, css

How can I place logo in center inline with menu? So the logo actually is inline but I want to center it with the items from the menu. Menu items starts from the bottom of the logo. How can I do this? Also tried to change the width of li but I couldn't do this, why?

```css
.logo {
  display: inline;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

#siteNav {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0px auto;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#siteNav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
}

#siteNav li {
  border-right: 1px solid #797979;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}

#siteNav li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

#siteNav a {
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  font-family: 'Mada', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000000;
  height: 55px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="siteNav">
  <img class="logo" src="images/img2-logo.png" alt="">
  <ul>
    <li><a>MISSION</a></li>
    <li><a>CLIENTS</a></li>
    <li><a>PRODUCTS</a></li>
    <li><a>CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hope you know `img` will target all images on your page. Use some stricter selector like `#siteNav img` or better `#siteNav .logo`

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't work bud.

Comment: The code snippet does work, it's just got a text `color` of white on a white background for some reason.

Comment: It sounds like you want the image actually *in* your menu. Is this not the case? Can you explain what you want in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

CSS flexbox is a good choice here. The `align-items` property will help you center the these elements. Here is a fabulous resource for more detail on the flexbox approach: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
#siteNav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

#siteNav img {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
#siteNav ul {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking for but this is my best guess.

Personally, I use CSS grid for everything. You can learn more [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

A quick explanation is that you need to define the grid layout in the parent container:

```
#siteNav {
    display: grid;
    grid: auto / repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
}
```

You weren't using your logo class, but I did. I also linked a different logo since your logo URL is a local one we can't see.

```
.logo {
    display: grid;
    grid: auto / repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
}
```

Then I needed to define where your menu items would fall into the grid:

```
#siteNav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    justify-self: center;
}
```

Definitely check out the link up top about CSS grid. It's super useful.

```css
#siteNav {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 0px auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #2780bc;
    display: grid;
    grid: auto / repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.logo {
  height: 50px;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  justify-self: center;
}

#siteNav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    justify-self: center;
}

#siteNav li {
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}

#siteNav li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

#siteNav a {
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 50px;
    font-family: 'Mada', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 55px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="siteNav">
                <img class="logo" src="https://mathiasbynens.github.io/stack-exchange-logos/so-logo.svg" alt="">
                <ul>
                    <li><a>MISSION</a></li>
                    <li><a>CLIENTS</a></li>
                    <li><a>PRODUCTS</a></li>
                    <li><a>CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```